# Some help figuring out what's wrong with my Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: java, sieve-of-eratosthenes

So... I have a bit of a problem in a lab. I've been at it for a while, but my program just isn't doing what I'm expecting it to do. I'm currently writing a Sieve of Eratosthenes program in Java. Unfortunately, it's not giving the expected output of a list of primes. I can't, for the life of me, figure out what's wrong... Could anyone here give me a pointer as to where I might have messed something up?

Much thanks!

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;
public class primeSieve {

/**
 * @param args
 */ 

public static void main(String[] args){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Get user input
    System.out.println("Please enter the first number of the set of numbers to calculate primes (first number MUST be prime):");
    int first = kb.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter the last number of the set of numbers to calculate primes (first number MUST be prime):");
    int last = kb.nextInt();

    List<Integer> primeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    //Make array with values from 2 to the last value entered by user
    for(int i = 2; i <= last; i++){
        numList.add(i);
    }

    int size = numList.size();

    //Calculate primes
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {   
        if(i != 0 && i % 2 == 0){continue;} //No point in checking even numbers
        if(numList.get(i) == 0){continue;}  //If a value has been removed, it's been set to 0. No need to check it.

        int prime = numList.get(i);         //The current number being worked on. Should be prime
        primeList.add(prime);               //The number is prime, put it into the prime list.
        for(int j = prime; j < size; j += prime) //Loop to remove multiples
        {
            numList.set(j, 0);  //Number is a multiple of the prime previously calculated. Set it to 0, not a prime.
        }
    }
    int primeSize = primeList.size();   
    System.out.println(primeSize);
    System.out.println("The prime numbers from " + first + " to " + last + " are:");
    for(int i = first; i < primeSize; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(primeList.get(i));
    }
}
```

}

Edit: The output for the program when I look for primes between 2 and 50 is this:

The prime numbers from 2 to 50 are:
7
13
19
25
31
39
43
49

Comment: For the output try --> for(int i = 0; i < primeSize; i++)

Comment: One problem is that `numList` starts at two, so the indices of the numbers don't match with the values in that list. Actually you don't need any values in that list (you are using it as the sieve), just zeroes and ones.

Comment: I think there is a little confusion here when you do "numList.set(j,0)". you see, j starts from the prime value, not the list index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the nested `for` loop, you start `j` at `prime`. However, consider the prime 2: it is at index 0, not index 2. Things should work out if you start `j` at `prime-first`. Also, as a commenter pointed out, your print loop should start at index 0 rather than `first`.